# Transform `not A` into `A -> False` in Coq

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

I want to prove `not A` by assuming `A` and finding `False`. What is the shortest and most generic way to transform goal `not A` into `A -> False`?

I tried `exfalso`, but it does not add `A` to my assumptions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest way is to do `intro x`, it will give you `x : A`.
`not A` is actually defined as `A -> False`, so it is already what you want:

```
not = fun A : Prop => A -> False
     : Prop -> Prop
```

If you really want to change your goal to `A -> False`, `unfold not` will do just fine.

Finally `exfalso` is tactic to replace the current goal with `False`. The aim is to state that the current context is inconsistent.